Is this a bug in saving a palette?
WARNING
This required me to kill Mathematica after it became completely unresponsive.
$Version is "14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"
(also for 14.0, same machine)
I make a palette like so
palette = 
  CreatePalette[Column[{Button["Click me", Print["Hello, World!"]]}]];

Then when I close the palette it prompts me about saving (which interestingly only happens if I move the palette from where it spawned, is that normal?). Now the usual windows explorer thing pops up and I can navigate. But if I don't save, and instead go to a different window or application, I have no way to get back to the save window, and mathematica, which is waiting for me to save the file, is unresponsive. the window has vanished.
I can't imagine why that would be desirable. Do others have this problem?

I replicated this problem (14.0, Windows 10)

Yes, this is an unfortunate issue that happens because the palette is a tool window. It is automatically hidden when the focus goes away, and it is shown again when you bring your notebook to focus. However, when the save dialog is opened, which is a modal window, waiting for your response, both windows will be hidden, but they will not be brought back on focus. I guess you can report this to WRI, and they can probably fix it.
You can either:
(1) Set WindowFloating inside CreatePalette to False to prevent the palette to be hidden when the focus goes away.
(2) Set Saveable inside CreatePalette to False so that the save dialog will not even appear.
(3) Or use some utility programs, such as WinLister, to manually close the window.

Here is a screenshot with the windows. When your notebook loses focus, both the palette and the save dialog will become invisible, but you can still close them within this app.

